# Want to place an apk on amazon store

Tags: android, amazon-s3, google-play

I want to place apk file of an application on Amazon app store.
Regarding this i want to know something related to Amazon app store.

For example one person download "xyz" application from Google Play Store . And than he starts downloading from Amazon. Since the package is same.
Will android allow this to install the same package with different app store.

I think the answer is no. But i am not sure about this.

If the answer is no. than we have to build apk with different package name?

If the answer is yes. than whether we check this that from which store this application was downloaded(because i have to implement different inapp method for both Google Play store and Amazon)

Comment: Thanks to this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683130/how-to-support-amazon-and-android-market-links-in-same-apk/7693295#7693295

Thats help me to find the solution.

Comment: Do you have the solution already? If so, please post it as an answer and mark it accepted ;)